# Whats the simplest way to do object recognition?

Tags: object-recognition

Given that I have harris corner detection and canny edge detection working, what is the simplest way to determine whether two images have corresponding edges or shape? The use case intended would be to classify really simple shapes and objects like a banana or a bottle.